# Possible to write command properties in a file

Tags: java, command-line, arguments, jmx

I need to run a Java programme with JMX feature, so the command would be similar like :

> java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10200
>   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=jmxremote.password -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=jmxremote.access

this makes the command line too long, is it possible to write the properties in a file, in order to shorten the command?
Or any other solutions will be welcome!

Comment: You could create a link or `.bat`-file for launching your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use property file (management.properties) which contains all the JMX options as shown below.

```
com.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10200
com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
....
```

But you have to tell where the JMX properties are available for the JVM by

**java -Dcom.sun.management.config.file=c:\management.properties**

Comment: Thank you Ramesh, would I know that if this file locate in Eclipse project, where I should place? In resources folder by default?

Comment: You can keep it anywhere, if you want to keep the file along with the the eclipse project workspace , you can use **-Dcom.sun.management.config.file=${workspace_loc:JMXTest/src/com/jmx/test}/management.properties** , where JMXTest is my project & com.jmx.test is my package